# c#/winforms: application wide keyboard shortcuts with exception on editable controls

Tags: c#, winforms

in my c#/winforms application i would like to do something like application wide keyboardshortcuts, which should be triggered anywhere, except if the focus is in a control where the user can edit text, like a textbox.

currently i am overwriting this function to do this.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData);
```

how can i add an exception to this, that it is not triggered when the user is in an editable control?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 solutions here.

1) in each editable control, handle all keyboard events and in the eventArgs object, set the Handled property to true;

e.Handled = true;

2) before executing the wide keyboard shortcut, look for the control which has the focus, and if it's a TextBox, ignore it. There's probably a method in each Form to tell what Control has the focus.

The second option is cleaner. I don't give code because I don't have Visual Studio open right now, but if you need more specific code you can ask.

PS: here, I did some googling for you: [How to Get FOcused Control?](http://www.csharpdeveloping.net/CodeSnippets.mvc/Detail/how_to_get_focused_control)